# Raspberry pi working as a network scanner

Tags: python, networking

I really want to use a raspberry pi to scan the network and to transfer the details to a web server. Apparently, I have planned on installing Nmap into the pi and use it to gather details of the devices connected to the network. But I am not exactly sure how I can achieve it.

Can anyone give any suggestions regarding this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could start by collecting the output of a nmap run within your program, then parsing its output.

For example, using Python I ran a quick 'ping only' scan of my local network. (Nmap also has an [XML output format](https://nmap.org/book/output-formats-commandline-flags.html#output-formats-flags-type) if you wish to be *really* thorough!).

```
import subprocess

command = [
    'nmap',
    '-sn',            # Ping scan only (was '-sP' in older nmap)
    '-oG', '-',       # Output 'grepable' format to stdout ('-')
    '192.168.0.0/24',
]

# This will take a few seconds.
result = subprocess.run(command, capture_output=True, check=True, text=True)

# For lack of something else to do...
for line in result.stdout.splitlines():
  print(line)
```

You now have something to work with! For the record here are the lines that are output on my network today:

```
# Nmap 7.91 scan initiated Wed Mar  3 10:34:29 2021 as: nmap -sP -oG - 192.168.0.0/24
Host: 192.168.0.1 (_gateway)    Status: Up
Host: 192.168.0.10 ()   Status: Up
Host: 192.168.0.11 ()   Status: Up
Host: 192.168.0.14 ()   Status: Up
Host: 192.168.0.17 ()   Status: Up
Host: 192.168.0.20 ()   Status: Up
Host: 192.168.0.22 (flash)  Status: Up
Host: 192.168.0.23 ()   Status: Up
Host: 192.168.0.100 ()  Status: Up
Host: 192.168.0.101 ()  Status: Up
Host: 192.168.0.102 ()  Status: Up
Host: 192.168.0.108 (pihole)    Status: Up
# Nmap done at Wed Mar  3 10:34:31 2021 -- 256 IP addresses (12 hosts up) scanned in 2.79 seconds
```